# Running without launching browser window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've literally just started looking into Selenium today, so please bear with me if I've missed something obvious. I'm attempting to build a small windows service that can monitor a few websites to check that they're up and running properly and check the performance of them (e.g. we've noticed CDN's operating slowly recently). So far I've included what I believe are the correct NuGet dependencies:

- Selenium WebDriver
- Selenium WebDrive Support Classes
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Then a very simple section of code to test:

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

This works fine and I can run this on multiple threads, wrap a stopwatch around them etc, but the one problem I've noticed is that this actually launches a browser dialog - whereas I really want to run in a 'headless' or 'windowless' mode. I can't [SimpleBrowserDriver](https://github.com/Teun/SimpleBrowser.WebDriver) but this doesn't put in extra requests to grab all relevant CSS & JavaScript for performance monitoring.

Comment: See [this](http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/) and [this](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/), they might be relevant.

Comment: @qqbenq: I've looked at those and I don't think they are. I believe I'm essentially doing the first in C#, and I'm not sure how to translate the 2nd into what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like phantomjs, or you could try running your tests through a service like BrowserStack. Phantomjs is a headless browser which you can launch from your script, and will provide you with the background browsing you are looking for. BrowserStack is one of a couple services through which you can route your tests; they handle the browser in the background while still offering the capability to view screenshots and run logs. BrowserStack offers a free trial but then is a paid service, so phantomjs might be a better option if it suits your goals.

Comment: Andrew - I want to be running this through a Windows Service however, logging results to a database, informing me of how long the site took to respond

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUNIT or PhantomJS would be your ideal solution, We do have a similar headless framework Building WebApps based on a CMS.
However PhantomJS and HTMLUnits does not Handle Native Browser Alerts and tests dependent will fail.
BrowserStack is a great solution but a lot will be taken into consideration When writing your test scripts such as more explicit waits as their machines can be pain especially when rending Java Script which tends to slow test and sometimes fails.

We engineered all relevant Logs, Screenshots and Response time to load a pages to be Saved and sent for access locally which i believe you can also store into a database with little effort.